# message reassembly / socket communication

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket which receives information in packets of 1024 characters or less. In those packets I some messages or parts thereof. Each message is ended with 2 characters.

The problem appears when there is fragmentation of messages across two packages. What algorithm do you recommend to handle this fragmentation? (I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel here, because I think this is a ubiquitous problem).

Example:

|011 012 013 014 \r\r 021 022 023 | 024 \r\r 031 032 033 | 034 \r\r 041 042 043 044 \r\r |

| ... | -> packet

xxx xxx ... \r\r -> a message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
buffer = ''

# reading loop
while True:

  data = socket.recv(1024)
  if not data:
    break

  # add the current data read by the socket to a temporary buffer
  buffer += data

  # search complete messages
  messages = buffer.split('\r\r')

  # we need at least 2 messages to continue
  if len(messages) == 1:
    continue

  # seperator found, iterate across complete messages
  for message in messages [:-1]:
    # handle here the message
    print message

  # set the buffer with the last cutted message
  buffer = messages [-1]
```

Comment: thanks, it works (with some small fixes). can you comment on your approach (is this a standard way of doing things, are there any unhandled conditions that could brake this, etc.)? I recognize the first part as the standard way to process file-like objects.

Comment: "standard way", i can't really tell about that, but this is how i'm doing in python and C from a long time :) (using memmem or custom algo to reconstruct and split).

Comment: but the main idea remain the same: read and append data to a temporary buffer, and use that buffer to discover and process messages. all unprocessed data remain in the buffer.