# How to use a generator to split socket read data on newlines

Tags: python, sockets

I have a simple generator that reads data from a socket and yields each chunk of data as it is received.

```
while True:
    data = s.recv(512)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data
```

The data looks like a csv file and so contains newlines.  How can I change my code to yield the lines of text instead of the buffer size?  I've played by with split('\n'), but always get stuck on how to detect the fact that last chunk might not be a complete line and I need to wait for the next chunk of data.

Thanks.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829148/message-reassembly-socket-communication

Comment: I'm curious, why are you limiting `recv()` to 512?  Also TCP or UDP?

Comment: That's just a number I picked for the question, it's actually a user configurable number in my real program. And I'm using TCP here but guess my question is more general.

Answer (score 5):

You could call [`socket.makefile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket#socket.socket.makefile) and then work with a file object (either iterate over lines or call `.readline()`):

```
import socket
from contextlib import closing

with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as s:
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8080))
    s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")

    with closing(s.makefile()) as f: #NOTE: closed independently
        for line in f:
            print line,

    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```